# Please advise which partitions I can delete

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    25167871    12582912   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *    25167872    25372671      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        25372672   127331189    50979259   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       127331251   312576704    92622727    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       127331253   312576704    92622726    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Here is my (inherited) current HDD set-up, Ubuntu 14.04
I want to remove all windows related partitions, as I've no intention of using Windows on this machine.

OS is showing 50Gb HDD, but when adding RAM, I noticed it has a 160Gb HDD!

I'm a novice when it comes to Linux so I'd appreciate some explicit detail, regarding what I've got and how best to remove it, but it looks to me that sda1 & sda4 are Windows and could be removed without harming my installation, but what of the other two?
I'm sure I can find the commands somewhere else on this forum...
Your help is appreciated.
Les

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the partition layout from the included Disks application?

Comment: All but /dev/sda3 are Windows partitions, but since you've inherited the HDD, it would be best to wipe all partitions while reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Android Dev.... I don't understand your request.

Comment: Cheers mikewhatever.... I had an inkling that the NTFS were Windows related just needed to check. thanks

Answer (score 2):

As mikewhatever said, only dev/sda3 seems to be linux related. If you don't have any important data on the drive it would be easier and quicker to just install ubuntu over the existing operating systems.

If you don't have a bootable disk/usb, boot into one of the working operating systems and burn one.

If you have a bootable usb or disk, just boot off of it, install Ubuntu and make sure to check the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option.

If you do want to save some of the data just copy it over to a flash drive or external hard drive.

Comment: Thanks KG, I'll do that eventually, need to sort the Boot media first, last time I installed Debian  I made some boot DVDs, but never got Web access...more research methinks. :D